# iOS/Android automation to interact with third party applications?

Tags: android, ios, automation, robotium, calabash

I'm looking for various automation suites that can automate iOS / Android. I have an application that uses the third party Video/Audio/Photo/ from the native OS. 


I was using Robotium with android before but I couldn't get it to take a photo/video/audio etc and research on google stated this wasn't possible.

I also attempted to use Calabash-iOs/ Calabash-Android but ran into the same problem when trying to take the video/photo/audio from an application outside the testing application.

Any recommendations for testing suite for iOS And/or Android?

Thanks!

Comment: Tried Calabash-iOS /  Monkeytalk (Bad documentation?) / Robotium.

Comment: calabash can take screenshots when your defined rules are met. have you tried zucchini. I haven't use it but heard it uses visual way of UAT(User acceptance Tests) https://github.com/playup/zucchini#readme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[uiautomator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/other-components/ui-automator) allows to automate features you need.**

It can access system features and pre-installed apps. UI Automator is an Android library [created by Google](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender/automate_ui_tests) that enables UI testing on visible elements on the screen, agnostic of the running application. UI Automator works with `AndroidJUnitRunner`, allowing developers to write complex, repeatable UI tests directly in Kotlin.

The drawbacks include:

1. Only languages for development are Java and/or Kotlin
2. It requires Android 4.3 (API level 18) or later

---

P.S. [Calabash](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android) and [Robotium](https://github.com/RobotiumTech/robotium) will not help to automate third party apps. I've used them both.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest you Appium, This tool gives you access to do the stuffs you are trying to do:

http://appium.io/

Comment: Yes thank you! I've switched over to appium /w ruby. I find this to be much easier. However I have not tried taking photo/video with appium. Have you had luck with that?